# c# WebClient returns 403 when downloading the file from remote URL

Tags: c#, url, webclient, http-status-code-403

When try to Download file, using WebClient, from remote website, I get an error: **The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.** It is reproducing only on one laptop. On my local laptop everything works fine. I am using the header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" but it is not helping. Anyway I can open that link manually and download that file. Are there any solutions of this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting user agent in header alone isn't sufficient. 403 means the web server is not able to authorize the request. Refer the common reasons for this error, https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989

Comment: Also for new development, you must use `HttpClient`, not the Webclient.